# Tensorflow stuck on first epoch | macOS

Tags: python, macos, tensorflow, keras, spyder

So as the title says, if I the following Python code on Spyder my machine freezes on the first epoch. What happens is: RAM usage goes to ~94%, after a while Spyder spits out a problem window but I get no error message in the console. The code just freezes.

I am doing this with more than 6M observations so I tried it with 10 and it worked. Then I tried with 100,000 and it works but very very slowly which I think is weird.

Can someone test this in their machine? It might be some package issue. Or it might be the code, I'm not too confident on the constrained_mse function.

The code:

```
from os import path
import pandas as pd
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
from tensorflow import keras
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.enable_eager_execution()
from tensorflow.keras import layers, losses
import numpy as np


# Hyperparameters
n_hidden_layers = 2 # Number of hidden layers.
n_units = 128 # Number of neurons of the hidden layers.
n_batch = 64 # Number of observations used per gradient update.
n_epochs = 30


# Create DataFrame (df) with random floats
call_df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(6000000, 6) * 100, 
                       columns=['Strike', "Time to Maturity", 
                                "Option_Average_Price", "RF Rate", 
                                "Sigma 20 Days Annualized", 
                                "Underlying Price"])
# call_df = call_df.iloc[-10:,:]

# Split call_df into random train and test subsets, for inputs (X) and output (y)
call_X_train, call_X_test, call_y_train, call_y_test = (train_test_split(
    call_df.drop(["Option_Average_Price"], axis = 1), 
    call_df.Option_Average_Price, test_size = 0.01))


# Create model using Keras' Functional API
def mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units):
    # Create input layer
    inputs = keras.Input(shape = (call_X_train.shape[1],))
    x = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha = 1)(inputs)

    # Create hidden layers
    for _ in range(n_hidden_layers):
        x = hl(x, n_units)

    # Create output layer
    outputs = layers.Dense(1, activation = keras.activations.softplus)(x)

    # Actually create the model
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    
    return model


# Hidden layer generation function
def hl(tensor, n_units):
    hl_output = layers.Dense(n_units, 
                             activation = layers.LeakyReLU(alpha=1))(tensor)
    return hl_output


# Custom loss function that is a MSE function plus three soft constraints
def constrained_mse(y_true, y_pred):
    
    mse = losses.mse(y_true, y_pred)
    
    x = tf.convert_to_tensor(call_X_train, np.float32)
    
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        tape.watch(x)
        with tf.GradientTape(persistent=True) as tape2:
            tape2.watch(x)
            y = model(x)
        
    grad_y = tape2.gradient(y, x)
    dy_dstrike = grad_y[0, 0]
    dy_dttm = grad_y[0, 1]
    
    grad_y2 = tape.gradient(y, x)
    d2y_dstrike2 = grad_y2[0, 0]
    
    loss = mse + dy_dstrike + dy_dttm + d2y_dstrike2

    return loss


model = mlp3_call(n_hidden_layers, n_units) 
model.compile(loss = constrained_mse, optimizer = keras.optimizers.Adam(),)
history = model.fit(call_X_train, call_y_train, batch_size = n_batch, 
                    epochs = n_epochs, validation_split = 0.01, verbose = 1)

# Save the model's architecture, weights and optimizer's state
directory = path.join("Saved_models", "mlp3_call_1")
model.save(directory)

# Save the model's train and validation losses for each epoch.
train_loss = history.history["loss"]
validation_loss = history.history["val_loss"]
numpy_train_loss = np.array(train_loss)
numpy_validation_loss = np.array(validation_loss)
np.savetxt("Saved_models/mlp3_call_1_train_losses.txt", 
            numpy_train_loss, delimiter=",")
np.savetxt("Saved_models/mlp3_call_1_validation_losses.txt", 
            numpy_validation_loss, delimiter=",")
```

EDIT: My machine is a Mac with 16GB of RAM and a 3210M 2.5GHz CPU. [This](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i5-2.5-13-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html) one, except mine has an SSD and 16GB of RAM

Comment: Can you post all your Mac specs from `Choose Apple menu  > About This Mac`

Comment: Are you running an Intel or M1 Mac?

Comment: It may be an issue that you are using a persistent GradientTape, and are not deleting it. This may lead to a memory leak, but I don't know for sure. You could try inserting `del tape2` after you are done with that tape. Or simply remove the persistency, as there seems to be no reason for this in your code.

Comment: @Luke done. No it's not an M1 Mac

Comment: @xdurch0 Tried removing `persistant = True` from the 2nd GradientTape and the computer takes longer until the Spyder problem window shows up and RAM usage goes down. So there was an improvement but no sucess.

In the meanwhile I tried testing the code on a Windows machine with TF-GPU and the code is running with 200k observations. If I try the full 6M it returns an OOM error.

Comment: Have you considered running the code on Google Colab?

Comment: @Luke Never did it before. Going to check it out.

Comment: Colab is perfect for your task and it has free GPU support as well.

Comment: @Luke I crashed Google Colab lol. "Your session crashed after using all available RAM". So my code has some optimization problem.